# Git Trying to commit a file restructure, no files have been edited

Tags: php, git, github

I have just begun learning the basics of Git.

I have installed Git locally and successfully integrated it to clone repos into my `xampps/htdocs`.

Now **locally**, in [this](https://github.com/Less-Git-It/php-learning-the-ropes) repo I have moved all the files into the *`php_Basics`* folder. But when I try and commit to sync up with my GitHub repo it says no changes added to commit.

How do I commit the file restructure, and sync it to the GitHub repo?

Comment: Did you `git init`?  Can you share other steps you've tried?

Comment: possibly `.gitignore`'d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Source:**[Reference](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/)

[Details about github](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/git-and-github-a-beginners-guide-for-complete-newbies)

1. Checklist------------------------------------
2. Move files to git cloned repository if not use git init then move files
3. configure git username
4. check status --- git status you will see changed files
5. git add file to staging for commit
6. git commit
7. git push

Comment: Thank you so much! I've written that down for future refernce. Although, in the VIm editor it says '# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
' How do I confirm my message and continue?

Comment: Press 'i' to Insert Mode in Vim Editor.

Comment: Once you have modified a file, press [Esc] shift to the command mode and press :w and hit [Enter] as shown below.

Comment: Save File in Vim. To save the file and exit at the same time, you can use the ESC and :x key and hit [Enter] . ...
Save and Exit File in Vim.

Answer (score 0):

Note: if the editor for the commit message is finicky, you can start with a shorter commit message in command line:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git add .
git commit -m "my message"
git push -u origin master
```